# Is the float switch broken?

Tags: dehumidifier

Does everything look alright or is there something wrong with the float switch? Thanks![image]

Friedrich model D35B1A. The "bucket full" light refuses to turn off. I think the float switch is in the right position but to no avail. I've tried unplugging the unit, but the "bucket full" light starts right up again. Pressing the "on/off" button doesn't seem to override anything. I had been manually draining the bucket without any problem in the days leading up to this issue.

Any help is much appreciated! This is someone else's humidifier, would hate to think I broke it somehow. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The "bucket full" switch is either in the wrong position, the bucket is not where it should be to allow the switch to work correctly or the switch has broken. Try moving the switch by hand after you remove the bucket. If you can not manually get the switch to work properly then I would assume that the switch has broken.

Answer (score 1):

Fredrich published information on the bucket and associated light. My first guess the bucket is not where it should be or something has been bent or damaged. Try holding the sensor in the not full position and see if the light goes out. My second is the sensor has failed, and third the control board failed. Does it have any warranty left?

Do you have the manual, if not you can find it here: https://f.hubspotusercontent40.net/hubfs/1669395/2020%20Literature%20PDFs/Installation%20and%20Operation%20Manuals/Dehumidifier%20Installation%20and%20Operation%20Manual_2020_D35B1A_D50B1A.pdf

Comment: Hi - I just noticed, is there a part missing on the float switch? I am having trouble finding a detailed diagram of the bucket and the float switch. I wish I could attach a photo but I don't have enough points.

Comment: You can contact Fredrich for a replacement part. There contact information is on the back of the manual. I could not copy it or I would have. Ther phone is 800-541-6645, They are in Texas so you might be able to reach them tonight. Good luck and let us know how you did.